# What to do with Q&A that changed after new OS release?

Tags: discussion

There are many Q&A on the site which were about some feature the OS didn't have at the time and therefore the accepted answer is **NO, something something, ...**

Now that changed with the new OS release and that feature **IS available, if you have OS version X.Y**. But those Q&As are not being updated.

**What is correct way to handle those Q&As?**

Comment on the Q or A seems very inappropriate to me. It can be overlooked and generally shouldn't be a source of information. Also may contain lots of information in those cases.

New answer on the question seems inconsistent as there would be always two correct answers, mostly with the older accepted (many of *old* OPs will not cooperate on this as they may not visit the site again), which would not be ideal in the long run.

Maybe create new question, tagged and formulated in the *new OS version*-way and cross-linked with the old question (and retag/reformulate the old question in the *old OS version*-way).

What do you think? Any other ideas?

And some examples:

- [Notifications queue](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/462/where-is-the-unread-notifications-queue)
- [Apps on SD](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2247/how-to-store-games-apps-on-an-sd-card)
- [BT file transfer](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/68/how-to-send-picture-or-video-over-bluetooth)
- [Internet sharing](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/80/how-can-i-connect-my-computer-to-internet-through-my-windows-phone-device) (maybe)
- [3g traffic counting](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/108/any-solution-for-3g-traffic-counting)
- [Forward in IE](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/214/where-is-the-forward-button-in-internet-explorer)

Answer (score 2):

Good question, I've been thinking about the same thing recently. Here's what I'd propose:

1. If there's no accepted answer, then post a new answer for the new version and let upvotes bring it to the top. Hopefully the OP will also come back to accept it.
2. If there is an accepted answer, but it basically just says "No" or "Not possible", then edit it to reflect that whatever was asked for is now possible in the latest version. Doesn't matter if it's your own answer or not. If you're really uncomfortable editing someone else's answer, leave a comment and wait for a bit to see if the author comes and edits it themselves.
3. However, if the accepted answer includes an actual solution which no longer applies to the latest version, then I think the best option would be to post a new question and link to the existing one if it helps provide context.

Of course, this only applies in cases where it's possible for users to upgrade from the older version to a newer one. For instance, questions specifically about WP7 (as seen from tags, device model mentioned in question, etc.) generally don't need answers explaining how to do it in WP8.

Comment: I like this - different situations requests different approach. 
I am not sure with the finish: "questions specifically about WP7 (as seen from tags, device model mentioned in question, etc.) generally don't need answers explaining how to do it in WP8" - it may be good to point out on such question that OS is evolving in good way.

Comment: Thing is, knowing that something is possible in WP8 doesn't help people with WP7 handsets because they can't upgrade their existing device. So such answers are basically equivalent to "buy a new phone", which isn't very helpful.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Maybe what I had on mind was more about comment on the right place than about answering.
Another view can be aging of such questions and therefore their declining relevance for new visitors coming from search engines.

Comment: Yeah, a comment would be totally appropriate for that sort of thing.

Comment: As long as #2 is just a small edit i.e. a footnote, then that is OK. Perhaps in a perfect world you would add a new answer and it would rise to the top...well at least that's what I have read on other site's meta.

Comment: Even if there is an accepted answer, I'd still advocate adding an answer that states it is "now possible since version x.y"

Comment: I guess it's a matter of personal preference. I'd prefer to keep the accepted answer as thorough as possible, but I can also see how having multiple answers can be beneficial. Certainly would help us up our [answers per question rating on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20757/windows-phone) a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

Its very complicated. My first approach has been edit the question with the news and make it visible that it is for an specific version.

**Edit**

Here are some examples:

[How do I silence Whatsapp notifications?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/how-do-i-silence-whatsapp-notifications/1946#1946)

[How can I turn off app notifications in Windows Phone 8?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/3638/60)

**End edit**

I don't like the idea of create a new question targeting the new version. We can end up full of duplicates.

Comment: I agree with not liking idea of lot of duplicate questions, but I think those outdated QAs maybe worse for some newcomers. Can you add an example of Q&A you are talking about? (to see what exactly is your proposal)

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ok, that seems acceptable to me. But what would be the rules of such update. Can I edit accepted answer that is not mine? Or - should I? What if there is no accepted? Should we edit the most voted question? Or add new one (as you did in the second example)?

Comment: In my opinion we could change an already accepted answer with the news. If it is not yours, in my opinion we should change too. Maybe we can flag for some moderator notice.

Comment: Like the one I put here below. But don't looks like a very good aproach. In case of a question with not accpected answer we could create a new one poiting to the change in version.

Answer (score 0):

The approach that I like is if the question is obviously version specific, to tag the question with the version. Then allow an additional question for each version where the answers are different.

If the answer is the same for all versions, group them together and don't tag by version.

Comment: Q&A that matches multiple versions - should it be always tagged with multiple version tags or with no version tag?